# How to hide/remove "From Messages" keyboard suggestion - Flutter IOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm creating a signup journey with phone, birthday, ssn, etc using the stepper widget. I'm using firebase for phone auth so on ios, it reads the message and there is a keyboard suggestion with the OTP code. However, the "From Messages - 12345" suggestion stays on the keyboard even after I've used it. It looks like it finally disappears after ~3-4 minutes but I need to hide/remove it right after the phone step. Initially I thought it might be because I'm using a stepper so it's technically one screen. I tried hiding and showing the keyboard to "refresh" the keyboard but the suggestion still shows on all my text fields.

I've tried the solutions here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22828
They don't work for me.

```
enableSuggestions: false,
autocorrect: false
```

I can't use `keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword` because my keyboard has to be numbers.